# Inserting javascript variable into json string

Tags: javascript, json, video, jwplayer

This should be super simple but I keep getting errors.

I have a JSON string that I need to add a js variable to, the code sample is below. Essentially I need to add frameVideo variable after the hash tag in the URL string.

```
var frameVideo = window.location.hash.substring(1);

jwplayer("sVid").setup({
'share-video': {
       'code': '<embed src="http://www.website.com/test.php#"\'.frameVideo.\'" width="480" height="270" allowfullscreen="true" />'
   },
});
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Your posted code is neither valid Javascript code, nor valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PHP concatenation instead of javascript style.

```
var frameVideo = window.location.hash.substring(1);

var JSON =  
{
       'code': '<embed src="http://www.website.com/test.php#"' + frameVideo + ' width="480" height="270" allowfullscreen="true" />'
   };
```

Comment: Wow that embarrassing, I completely missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of the `.` to concatenate your string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are just coming over to javascript from PHP, given the coding style. In javascript, we use `+` to concatinate, as opposed to the `.` in PHP.

JSON strings are essentially javascript objects:

```
var obj = {
    'share-video': {
        'code': '<embed src="http://www.website.com/test.php#' + frameVideo + '" width="480" height="270" allowfullscreen="true" />'
    }
}
```

You are also defining an index of an object outside of the context of an Object. `'variable':'something'` is a syntax error when outside of an object. Objects are encapsulated within `{` and `}`. The above code is semantically correct.

When debugging javascript, *always* check your console logs. They can help pinpoint exactly what is causing a problem. If you didn't know how to activate the console, it is accessed with `F12` in most browsers, or by right-click->inspect element. I recommend Google Chrome for javascript debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` for concatenation.
No need to escape anything here either.
You have an extra double quote after the `#`.
You want to use double quotes for key names in JSON (it probably wouldn't make a difference here, but a good habit regardless)
You have a trailing comma after your `"share-video"` object.

```
var frameVideo = window.location.hash.substring(1);

jwplayer("sVid").setup({
    "share-video": {
        "code": '<embed src="http://www.website.com/test.php#' + frameVideo + '" width="480" height="270" allowfullscreen="true" />'
    }
});
```